# gvfs-metadata and other metadata from veracrypt contrainer

Tags: encryption, 17.04, gvfs, metadata, veracrypt

I have a VeraCrypt container with valuable data. I do not want my system to store information on what is inside of this container including filenames and folder names. I have Ubuntu 17.04. Unfortunately I recently found a files in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/` containing full paths and filenames of many files in this encrypted container. Is there any way of stopping this and other files like it from existing?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two options:

### Don't use desktop environments or applications that depend on GVFS

This excludes most software based on GNOME but not software based merely on the GTK+ toolkit. You can try LXDE as a desktop environment and software suite because it tries to be lightweight and not depend on useful but non-crucial libraries like GVFS.

### Use full disk encryption

If you really want to be sure that no (meta-)data leaks into unencrypted regions the only way to be sure is to encrypt *everything*.

If you're less concerned you may find the encryption of your user home directory sufficient. Alternatively you can set up an encrypted area inside your home directory and move and sym-link `.local/share/gvfs-metadata` there.